# jenkins cli command gives error java.io.StreamCorruptedException: invalid stream header: 0A0A0A0A

Tags: jenkins, jenkins-cli

I am trying to execute jenkins cli command

```
java -jar /home/jenkins/jenkins-cli.jar -s http://jenkins.server.com/ version --username jenkins --password jenkins
```

> Getting following error
>
> Aug 05, 2015 6:01:02 AM
>   hudson.remoting.SynchronousCommandTransport$ReaderThread run SEVERE:
>   I/O error in channel Chunked connection to
>   http://jenkins.server.com/cli java.io.StreamCorruptedException:
>   invalid stream header: 0A0A0A0A   at
>   java.io.ObjectInputStream.readStreamHeader(ObjectInputStream.java:804)
>     at java.io.ObjectInputStream.(ObjectInputStream.java:299)     at
>   hudson.remoting.ObjectInputStreamEx.(ObjectInputStreamEx.java:40)
>     at
>   hudson.remoting.AbstractSynchronousByteArrayCommandTransport.read(AbstractSynchronousByteArrayCommandTransport.java:34)
>     at
>   hudson.remoting.SynchronousCommandTransport$ReaderThread.run(SynchronousCommandTransport.java:48)
>
> hudson.remoting.RequestAbortedException:
>   java.io.StreamCorruptedException: invalid stream header: 0A0A0A0A     at
>   hudson.remoting.Request.abort(Request.java:296)   at
>   hudson.remoting.Channel.terminate(Channel.java:815)   at
>   hudson.remoting.SynchronousCommandTransport$ReaderThread.run(SynchronousCommandTransport.java:69)
>     at ......remote call to Chunked connection to
>   http://jenkins.server.com/cli(Native Method)  at
>   hudson.remoting.Channel.attachCallSiteStackTrace(Channel.java:1361)
>     at hudson.remoting.Request.call(Request.java:171)   at
>   hudson.remoting.Channel.call(Channel.java:752)    at
>   hudson.remoting.RemoteInvocationHandler.invoke(RemoteInvocationHandler.java:179)
>     at hudson.remoting.$Proxy1.waitForProperty(Unknown Source)  at
>   hudson.remoting.Channel.waitForRemoteProperty(Channel.java:1205)  at
>   hudson.cli.CLI.(CLI.java:147)   at
>   hudson.cli.CLIConnectionFactory.connect(CLIConnectionFactory.java:72)
>     at hudson.cli.CLI._main(CLI.java:479)   at
>   hudson.cli.CLI.main(CLI.java:390)

Caused by:

> java.io.StreamCorruptedException: invalid stream header: 0A0A0A0A     at
>   java.io.ObjectInputStream.readStreamHeader(ObjectInputStream.java:804)
>     at java.io.ObjectInputStream.(ObjectInputStream.java:299)     at
>   hudson.remoting.ObjectInputStreamEx.(ObjectInputStreamEx.java:40)
>     at
>   hudson.remoting.AbstractSynchronousByteArrayCommandTransport.read(AbstractSynchronousByteArrayCommandTransport.java:34)
>     at
>   hudson.remoting.SynchronousCommandTransport$ReaderThread.run(SynchronousCommandTransport.java:48)

Comment: possible duplicate of [Possible causes for "StreamCorruptedException: invalid stream header"](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3837574/possible-causes-for-streamcorruptedexception-invalid-stream-header)

Comment: question is totally different.

Answer (score 6):

Go to Configure Global Security > TCP port for JNLP agents and chose Random
save and run your command again

Comment: This fixed it for me and didn't require a restart.

Answer (score 4):

It seems this is a similar problem as:
https://issues.jenkins-ci.org/browse/JENKINS-23232

It suggests that you can add in your Jenkins system config:

**JAVA_ARGS="-Dhudson.diyChunking=false"**

(in /etc/sysconfig/jenkins for **RHEL** ; /etc/default/jenkins for **Ubuntu/Debian**)

You will need to do a restart of the Jenkins server

Answer (score 0):

The only thing that worked for me was:

```
sudo apt-get install openjdk-7-jre
```