# java.io.StreamCorruptedException: invalid stream header: 0A0A0A0A

Tags: ubuntu, jenkins, groovy, chef-infra

I am trying to install jenkins using [chef cookbook](https://supermarket.chef.io/cookbooks/jenkins) Trying to set up a Master and Slave and also set the users and the authentication. Using Microsoft Azure ubuntu 14.04 system. 
I am running a recipe to create a user.

```
jenkins_password_credentials 'wcoyote' do
  id 'xyz'
  description 'Wile E Coyote'
  password    'beepbeep'
end
```

When I run the above recipe I get the follow issue. 
I am getting the error mentioned below.

```
Chef Client failed. 1 resources updated in 48 seconds
[2016-06-27T11:22:50+00:00] FATAL: Stacktrace dumped to /home/ubuntu/.chef/local-mode-cache/cache/chef-stacktrace.out
[2016-06-27T11:22:50+00:00] FATAL: Please provide the contents of the stacktrace.out file if you file a bug report
[2016-06-27T11:22:50+00:00] ERROR: jenkins_script[configure settings] (jenkins-server::settings line 2) had an error: Mixlib::ShellOut::ShellCommandFailed: Expected process to exit with [0], but received '255'
---- Begin output of "java" -jar "/home/ubuntu/.chef/local-mode-cache/cache/jenkins-cli.jar" -s http://localhost:8080 groovy /tmp/groovy20160627-35450-nud0ab ----
STDOUT:
STDERR: Jun 27, 2016 11:22:50 AM hudson.remoting.SynchronousCommandTransport$ReaderThread run
SEVERE: I/O error in channel Chunked connection to http://localhost:8080/cli
java.io.StreamCorruptedException: invalid stream header: 0A0A0A0A
    at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readStreamHeader(ObjectInputStream.java:807)
    at java.io.ObjectInputStream.<init>(ObjectInputStream.java:302)
    at hudson.remoting.ObjectInputStreamEx.<init>(ObjectInputStreamEx.java:48)
    at hudson.remoting.AbstractSynchronousByteArrayCommandTransport.read(AbstractSynchronousByteArrayCommandTransport.java:34)
    at hudson.remoting.SynchronousCommandTransport$ReaderThread.run(SynchronousCommandTransport.java:59)

hudson.remoting.RequestAbortedException: java.io.StreamCorruptedException: invalid stream header: 0A0A0A0A
    at hudson.remoting.Request.abort(Request.java:303)
    at hudson.remoting.Channel.terminate(Channel.java:847)
    at hudson.remoting.SynchronousCommandTransport$ReaderThread.run(SynchronousCommandTransport.java:92)
    at ......remote call to Chunked connection to http://localhost:8080/cli(Native Method)
    at hudson.remoting.Channel.attachCallSiteStackTrace(Channel.java:1416)
    at hudson.remoting.Request.call(Request.java:172)
    at hudson.remoting.Channel.call(Channel.java:780)
    at hudson.remoting.RemoteInvocationHandler.invoke(RemoteInvocationHandler.java:249)
    at hudson.remoting.$Proxy1.waitForProperty(Unknown Source)
    at hudson.remoting.Channel.waitForRemoteProperty(Channel.java:1258)
    at hudson.cli.CLI.<init>(CLI.java:141)
    at hudson.cli.CLIConnectionFactory.connect(CLIConnectionFactory.java:72)
    at hudson.cli.CLI._main(CLI.java:473)
    at hudson.cli.CLI.main(CLI.java:384)
Caused by: java.io.StreamCorruptedException: invalid stream header: 0A0A0A0A
    at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readStreamHeader(ObjectInputStream.java:807)
    at java.io.ObjectInputStream.<init>(ObjectInputStream.java:302)
    at hudson.remoting.ObjectInputStreamEx.<init>(ObjectInputStreamEx.java:48)
    at hudson.remoting.AbstractSynchronousByteArrayCommandTransport.read(AbstractSynchronousByteArrayCommandTransport.java:34)
    at hudson.remoting.SynchronousCommandTransport$ReaderThread.run(SynchronousCommandTransport.java:59)
---- End output of "java" -jar "/home/ubuntu/.chef/local-mode-cache/cache/jenkins-cli.jar" -s http://localhost:8080 groovy /tmp/groovy20160627-35450-nud0ab ----
Ran "java" -jar "/home/ubuntu/.chef/local-mode-cache/cache/jenkins-cli.jar" -s http://localhost:8080 groovy /tmp/groovy20160627-35450-nud0ab returned 255
[2016-06-27T11:22:52+00:00] FATAL: Chef::Exceptions::ChildConvergeError: Chef run process exited unsuccessfully (exit code 1)
```

Comment: Is this the same as: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31824605/jenkins-cli-command-gives-error-java-io-streamcorruptedexception-invalid-stream ?

Comment: Probably yes, but this solution provided is not working for me. Also I am using chef to bootstrap jenkins master and slave

Comment: Using Chef doesn't change the underlying commands that get run. If that command fails, then Chef fails. Make the command not fail :)

Comment: How do I do that ? Suggestion will help :)